# Play video from Parse Server(Android)

Tags: android, video, parse-server

I have an app that can upload a short 10s video to Parse Server in .mp4 format. The video is being saved as a file object.

I would like to play that video in an android VideoView, I have the video view set up and would like to get the setVideoURI to point to the video saved in my video class in Parse Server. The video player loads but the video never plays. Here's what i looks like -

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Videos"); //"Videos" is the class

    query.whereEqualTo("username", activeUserName); //active user has video in Parse
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                if (objects.size() > 0) {

                    for (ParseObject object : objects) {

                        final ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("VideoName"); //"VideoName" is where the mp4 file is stored

                        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

                                if (e == null && data != null) {

                                    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
                                    //This may be wrong
                                    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("VideoName"));

                                    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(VideoFeedActivity.this);

                                    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

                                    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

                                    videoView.start();
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: The video player loads, but the video does not play.

Comment: anything in your logs?

Comment: Nope, no error in the log. Perhaps i'm retrieving the object incorrectly? I updated the code above and included the object.get function.